# A better you, _____?

Tags: phrase-request

I am coming up with a slogan.

A better you, _____.

1. a bigger world
2. a broader world
3. a better world
4. a bigger stage
5. a bigger difference
6. A bigger playground

Which of them make(s) sense to western readers?

Here is my intended meaning:

Suppose a person lives in a remote area. If they go out to big cities to work, they can see more life, have broader horizons and make a bigger difference to the world.

Comment: No matter which you choose, I think you have it backwards. Axioms like this often go *cause*, *effect*. Regardless of your metaphor, the city, (or the world, or the proverbial playground) isn't getting bigger because of our improvements. Instead, we are improving because we are living in a bigger, a better place. So it shouldn't be, e.g., _A better me, a bigger world_ . Instead, I think, _A bigger world, a better me_ says it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct but the purpose of the slogan need only be clear to you based on your intention. I would take #3 A better world. Such slogans work on similar words (better/better) or somewhat similar sounding words (bigger/better). These form a couplet that is easier to remember and then sell.

You could also add a *few* words to change the direction as indicated in the comment. 
A better me *makes a* bigger world. Or vice versa. A better world *makes a* better me.
or A better me *from a* bigger world. So long as the ends are catchy and the middle is not long the idea will get across.